# If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$ then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\iff\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I want to prove the following statement

> If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$ then 
>   $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\iff\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=0$

One side of the proof is easy. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=0$. By our assumption we also know that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}=0$ then we have

$$0=\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1$$
which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1.$$
Now, let us go the other side. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$. This is again equivalent to $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}=0$. I am stuck right here!

> Is there any need for further assumptions to carry out the proof from this side?

Comment: Add some brackets.

Comment: @Adam: OK. I though it is evident! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)=g(x)+1$ and $\lim_{n\to a}g(x)=\infty$ then also $\lim_{n\to a}f(x)=\infty$, and: $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\left(1+\frac1{g(x)}\right)=1$$

But $f(x)-g(x)=1$ so there will be no convergence to $0$.

Comment: For example, $a=0$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: That's a good counter example. Can we add any further condition to get what we want?

Comment: I am afraid that further conditions (I don't see any yet) will have to be quite restricting. This because convergence to $\infty$ gives both functions much freedom concerning the values they can take. This freedom is of course a bit tempered by the condition that their quotiënt must converge to $1$. But they ($f$ and $g$) can simply "decide" to stay away from eachother at least some positive constant.

Comment: The difference need not even be bounded. Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-a)^2} + \frac{1}{x-a}$, $g(x) = \frac{1}{(x-a)^2}$.